# Discord py: How to say hello to a new user?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello I am starting to program my first bot for discord in python, and I find myself with a small problem and it is that although it seems that the code is correct it seems that it is not doing anything at all.

The idea is that the bot listens when a new user joins the server and then greets them on a specific channel

This is the code:
Edit: I have added the new code that I have right now, however the problem persists, the intirenances are also activated from the discord developer portal.

I also want to add that the bot has an on_ready with a print ("Is working") to check if the bot is started correctly.

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

#Bot prefix
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)

#Event
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    get(member.guild.channels, id=768670193379049483)
    await channel.send(f"{member} Welcome") ```
````

Comment: You should add `bot.run('TOKEN')` at the end

Comment: It contains it, I just didn't put it on for privacy reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable intents.members

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Edit:

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(id)
# or
channel = get(member.guild.channels, id=some_id)
```

So your code would look like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = get(member.guild.channels, id=768670193379049483)
    await channel.send(f'{member} welcome')
```

- [A Primer to Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, without a doubt it is one of the reasons why it should not be working, however I just enabled them and added those lines to the code and it continues exactly the same.

Comment: `bot.get_channel(id)` not `get_channel(id)` you should also change that

Comment: or `get(member.guild.channels, id=your_id)`

Comment: That's odd, any errors? could you try printing `channel`?

Comment: I can print the channel id without problems in the console, https://i.imgur.com/rftPQH1.png https://i.imgur.com/qWpyHwI.png

Comment: There's a typo in `bot.get_channel`  https://imgur.com/a/TINXSkX

Comment: Thanks I had not realized it, however it remains the same, I think I am going to look for some example codes to see if there are other ways

Comment: try [this](https://gist.github.com/Kwieeciol/5d40340cf75a6b1839403118a0daabd2) if it's not working something is wrong.

Comment: I really appreciate it from my heart, it finally worked xD